# Proofs by Induction: Using Statement(k-1) to prove Statement(k) vs. Using Statement(k) to prove Statement(k+1)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, induction

Regarding the principle of induction, my textbook (Essentials of Discrete Mathematics by David J Hunter, 3ed) states (pg 191 print format):

*To prove that closed-form solution $f(n)$ matches a recurrence relation $R(n)$, we had to prove the following:*

*For all $n ≥ 1, R(n) = f(n)$.*

*We did this by first checking the base case $R(1)=f(1)$, and then proving that $R(k) = f(k)$ follows from the inductive hypothesis $R(k-1) = f(k-1)$, for any $k > 1$.*

I feel like I conceptually understand the examples provided, but I am greatly struggling to apply the concepts to any problems/exercises, especially in terms of where/how to start.

I have tried lots of google and youtube for guidance, but everything I find seems to be following a different approach: Using as inductive hypothesis *$k$* and then proving *$k + 1$*.

I can follow along with the examples in this approach as well, but when it comes time to apply my understanding to my homework in the format expected by my professor (using $k-1$ to prove $k$, like in the textbook), I can't seem to figure out how to translate the "getting started advice" to work this way.

**My question is this: how do I come up with an inductive hypothesis in terms of $k-1$? And how to then jump into the inductive step to show $k$, in terms of manipulating $k-1$?**

I realize this may be impossible to answer as a general question, but I don't want to say "here's my homework, how do I do it?" I want to know how to apply concepts to the solving of various problems.

Thank you.

(Please note, I have a math learning disorder but through persistence and research and strenuous practice, I am usually eventually able to "get" the concepts and work with them. It's usually a matter of seeking multiple different explanations/approaches for the same topic and then practice practice practice.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental logic of induction is that if

> some proposition is true for the number $1$

and

> the truth of the proposition for any particular number implies its
> truth for *the next number*

then

> the proposition is true for all positive integers.

There is nothing in this logic about "$k$ and $k+1$" or
"$k-1$ and $k$". Both those expressions are ways to describe "a number and the next number". You can begin the inductive step by saying

> Suppose the proposition is true for $k$

and deduce its truth for $k+1$

or

> Suppose the proposition is true for $k-1$

and deduce its truth for $k$.

I suggest you look at some inductive proof you understand that uses one of these conventions and try to rewrite it so that it uses the other. Then you will see how they express the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your taking the time to answer. I'm not struggling with the concepts you described above, I'm struggling with how to actually apply them to the actual problems. Like how do I know what the inductive hypothesis should be if I'm not proving the induction "on n"? An example: proving the construction of a palindrome (string) by a certain recursive definition provided by the textbook. Also I cannot seem to find any example proofs that prove the induction "on" these open-for-interpretation properties.

Comment: You're welcome. The way to thank someone here is to accept the answer (the checkmark), You can also upvote   answers (the  uparrow) on any question, Including one you accepted on your own question. Your comment is actually asking another question, which you should post as another question. Phrase it carefully and show us what you have tried.